# Dynamic CSV generated file downloads with UTF characters

Tags: javascript, encodeuricomponent

So I have this code that creates a download dynamically from any array of objects with matching keys (I got it from another SO question, I'd love to credit the author, but I can't find the link):

```
var objectToCSVRow = function(dataObject) {
  var dataArray = new Array;
  for (var o in dataObject) {
    var innerValue = dataObject[o]===null?'':dataObject[o].toString();
    var result = innerValue.replace(/"/g, '""');
    result = '"' + result + '"';
    dataArray.push(result);
  }
  return dataArray.join(';') + '\r\n';
}

var exportToCSV = function(arrayOfObjects) {
  if (!arrayOfObjects.length) {
    return;
  }
  var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

  // headers
  csvContent += objectToCSVRow(Object.keys(arrayOfObjects[0]));

  arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(item){
    csvContent += objectToCSVRow(item);
  }); 

  var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
  link.setAttribute("download", "customers.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link); 
}
```

It works fine, but when I try to include UTF-8 chars:

```
exportToCSV([{spanishChars:"ñé"}])
```

the encodeURI() function encodes them and I get this:

[image]

Is there a way I can create downloadable content without having to use encodeURI() or is there a way, at least, to have encodeURI() work with the special chars?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't really reproduce that, https://jsfiddle.net/pfL0gohc/ Downloading the generated CSV and opening it, shows the characters `ñé` quite fine. (Tested in Chrome, and CSV opened with Numbers on a Mac, but I doubt this has much influence.)

Comment: Sorry, I realized later that the issue was only with MS excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `BOM` character on the first line of the CSV.

```
  var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
  // add BOM - always on the first line of the csv
  csvContent += '\uFEFF';
  // headers
  csvContent += objectToCSVRow(Object.keys(arrayOfObjects[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks!! :) I should have suspected Microsoft from the start, I can't believe I wasted so much time on this.